# Lazy Loading with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript

This is my lazy loader for functions:

```
var make_lazy = function (calledFunc, a, b, c, d, e, f) {
    return function () {
        return calledFunc(a, b, c, d, e, f)
    }
};
```

It works with most functions except this one:

```
function superAdd() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments).reduce(function (a, c) {
        return a + c;
    }, 0);
}
```

How do I modify this function to accept a variable number of arguments? I tried using the arguments object with no success.

Comment: Where are you calling `superAdd`? Can you show a complete example of the implementation that's not working?

Comment: @Josh Beam
I'm using a unit test var lazy_value = make_lazy(superAdd, 3, 5);

Test.expect(lazy_value() === 15, 'Evaluates the expression when required');

Comment: `function make_lazy(fn, args) {return Function.apply.bind(fn, this, args);};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * @param args {Array}
 */
var make_lazy = function(calledFunc, args) {
  return function () {
    return calledFunc.apply(this, args);
  }
};

var lazy = make_lazy(superAdd, [3, 5]);

lazy(); // => 8
```

With the above, you can just group your indeterministic amount of arguments into an array.

The way the above works is because you have a variable number of arguments, only after the *first* argument (which is deterministic).

With ES6, it's even cooler, using the spread operator:

```
function make_lazy(calledFunc, ...args) {
  return () => calledFunc(...args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use arguments along with .apply on the callback function like you are doing for the slice function

```js
var make_lazy = function (calledFunc) {
    return function () {
       return calledFunc.apply(null,arguments);
    }
};

function one(a){
   console.log("how many args: "+arguments.length,a);
}
function two(a,b){
   console.log("how many args: "+arguments.length,a,b);
}
function three(a,b,c){
   console.log("how many args: "+arguments.length,a,b,c);
}

var onelazy = make_lazy(one);
var twolazy = make_lazy(two);
var threelazy = make_lazy(three);
onelazy(1);
twolazy(1,2);
threelazy(1,2,3);
```

Or if you are wanting to pass predefined values as arguments, just get the arguments from within the make_lazy function itself (less the first argument), and use that for the apply call.

```
var make_lazy = function (calledFunc) {
    var args = [].splice.call(arguments,1);
    return function () {
       return calledFunc.apply(null,args);
    }
};
function two(a,b){
   console.log("Num Args: "+arguments.length,a,b);
}
var twoLazy = make_lazy(two,3,5);
twoLazy();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the problem you are having with the arguments version of the `make_lazy` function is that you are using the wrong arguments list, such as:

```
    var make_lazy = function (calledFunc) {
      return function () {
        return calledFunc.apply(null, arguments);
      };
    };
```

the `arguments` in that statement references the returned function's arguments, such that

```
    var lazy = make_lazy(superAdd, 1, 2, 3);
    lazy(3,4,5);
    // returns 12 -not- 6
```

because it is only taking in the arguments that are applied at `lazy`'s execution. The `make_lazy` function should store the arguments at its run time so that it can use it later.

So to answer your question, store `arguments` as a variable outside of the scope of the inner returned function:

```
    var make_lazy = function (calledFunc) {

      // Remove the calledFunc from the arguments list by passing in `1` to slice.
      var lazyArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

      return function () {
        return calledFunc.apply(null, lazyArgs);
      };
    };
```